# How to fasten Bitmap.SetPixel without using unsafe method?

Tags: getpixel

How can I fasten Bitmap Set/GetPixel method without using unsafe mode or any other solutions from codeproject like FastPixel or FastBitmap (which actually also uses unsafe mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found the answer
Use System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy and no unsafe keyword is needed!
Almost the same effective as unsafe method and still way way faster than get/sex pixel.

http://davidthomasbernal.com/blog/2008/03/13/c-image-processing-performance-unsafe-vs-safe-code-part-i/